# Why does torchvision pretrained model perform better than scratch trained?

Tags: pytorch, image-segmentation, torchvision

I followed the torchvision tutorial (https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html) and trained a segmentation model on my own dataset of aerial images. Which only has 2 classes. The result were:

```
Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.640
Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.700
```

[image]

Decent but I would like to improve the accuracy of the masks.

So I then trained exactly the same with `pretrained=False` and `pretrained_backbone=False` and was very surprised that the performance was about half of the pre-trained model.

```
Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.328
Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.472
```

I'm trying to understand why this would be the case and where I should be directing my effort to improve the model:

- Training parameters like: lr, momentum, dropout, batch size ..
- Architecture of the MaskRCNN network: roi, anchors ..
- Something about my dataset: adding augmentation ..

I'm not sure where to look to understand how I can improve the performance. What is a decent way to approach that?

EDIT: My model is:

```
def get_model_instance_segmentation(num_classes):
    # load an instance segmentation model pre-trained pre-trained on COCO
    model = torchvision.models.detection.maskrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=True)

    # get number of input features for the classifier
    in_features = model.roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.in_features
    # replace the pre-trained head with a new one
    model.roi_heads.box_predictor = FastRCNNPredictor(in_features, num_classes)

    # now get the number of input features for the mask classifier
    in_features_mask = model.roi_heads.mask_predictor.conv5_mask.in_channels
    hidden_layer = 256
    # and replace the mask predictor with a new one
    model.roi_heads.mask_predictor = MaskRCNNPredictor(in_features_mask, hidden_layer, num_classes)
    return model
```

Comment: They use the Feature Pyramid Network for feature extraction before passing into the Region Proposal Network. Which, I believe, makes them more accurate than other. In my case too, when I tried to replace default resnet50 with vgg16, the accuracy difference was very huge. I think that helps!

Comment: @SubashKharel I'm not quite sure I understand. I've edited my question to show what model I'm using

Comment: @SubashKharel are you saying that vgg was a big improvement over resnet50 as the backbone?

Comment: Nope, its the other way.